# elastic IP breaks app server communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, glassfish, ejb, rmi

I'm running a Glassfish app server on my EC2 box.  A desktop client communicates with it using standard remote Java RMI/EJB lookups.  When I use the public IP that EC2 gives me, my app works great.  My desktop client can communicate with Glassfish with no problem.

When I switch to using an Elastic IP, the desktop app can no longer communicate with the EC2 instance in both directions. My suspicion is that Glassfish is giving the wrong external IP address to the desktop client when a connection is made.

I've tried many permutations of network config, including putting the Elastic IP in /etc/hosts and using the EIP domain name in the server config, etc, etc.

How can I get my local EC2 box to return the EIP instead of whatever it thinks it's IP is on the inside.  Again, this is not a problem with an EC2 public IP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the public DNS domain name (the one that looks like `ec2-52-12-34-567compute-1.amazonaws.com`) in place of the `0.0.0.0` host entries in domain.xml, but DON'T change the node host from the default of localhost.

Leave `/etc/hosts` as it is. Using a public IP for 'hostname' will prevent Glassfish from starting.